# Spark MLlib Single precision distributed matrix

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, gpu, nvblas

Is it possible to create a distributed blockmatrix containing single precision entries in spark?

From what i gather from the documentation, the scala/java implementation of blockmatrix requires a mllib.Matrix object, which holds the values as doubles. 
Is there any way around this limitation?

Background: 
Im using GPU's to accelerate Sparks distributed matrix multiplication routines, and my GPU performs 20 times slower when multiplying double precision matrices rather than single precision matrices.